# How do I get array inside array datain Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

[[image]]

Please how do I get the MentorProfile data's
I already iterate for the main data coming...

```
 <div v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id">
        <div v-for="profile in notification.MentorProfile" :key="profile.id">
            
            <q-item clickable v-ripple>
            <q-item-section>
                {{ notification.text }} from 
            </q-item-section>
            
            <q-item-section avatar>
            <q-avatar rounded>
                <img src="../assets/mentor.jpg">

            </q-avatar>
            </q-item-section>
            <span>{{ profile.name }}</span>
        </q-item>
        
      <q-separator />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can just use another `v-for` inside of your other one, e.g. `v-for"post in mentor.MentorsPosts"`.

Comment: But please am having similar code in another component and i used the same method but didnt work. 
I added the code at top...@StevenB.

Comment: `notification.MentorProfile` is not an array. It is an object. You can not use `v-for` on an object. Do not use the second `v-for`. Instead of `profile.name` you need to use `notification.MentorProfile.name`.

Comment: Please post how your data is structured.

Comment: It worked using notifiction.MentorProfile.name... Thanks @InvisibleGorilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      notifications: [{id: 1, file: 'file1', text: 'notification text', MentorProfile: [{id: 1, name: 'Mentor 1'}]}]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id">
    <p>{{ notification.text }} from </p>
    <div v-for="profile in notification.MentorProfile" :key="profile.id">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/20">
      <span>{{ profile.name }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```